# How to register and resolve open generic with two type arguments as interface with one type argument using Autofac

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, autofac, simple-injector, open-generics

### Problem

I have a number of concrete, generic classes with two type arguments that implement a generic interface with one type argument.  For example:

```
public interface ISomeService<T>
{
    // ...
}

public class SomeService<TA, TB> : ISomeService<TA>
{
    // ...
}
```

I register them using Autofac like this:

```
var containerBuilder = new ContainerBuilder();

containerBuilder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(SomeService<,>))
    .As(typeof(ISomeService<>))
    .InstancePerLifetimeScope();

var container = containerBuilder.Build();
```

When attempting to resolve an instance of `ISomeService<Foo>` like this:

```
var service = container.Resolve<ISomeService<Foo>>();
```

I get an `Autofac.Core.Registration.ComponentNotRegisteredException` exception saying that the requested service `` ISomeService`1[[Foo]] `` has not been registered.

### Questions

1. Is what I'm trying to do impossible using Autofac?
2. If so, is there a workaround?
3. If not, do other DI containers offer such a capability, e.g. SimpleInjector?

Comment: How would the container know the type `TB`?

Comment: @YacoubMassad Good question.  I suspected that was the root of the problem.  So how do I register the service without having to explicitly register each generic type individually (e.g. `containerBuilder.RegisterType<SomeService<Foo, Bar>>().As<ISomeService<Foo>>()`?

Comment: The type `TB` is an implementation detail of `SomeService<TA, TB>`, and not something that I would want to leak up to the `ISomeService<T>` interface.

Comment: Do all implementations have the same value for `TB`?

Comment: @Steven - No, unfortunately not.  In reality, `TA` and `TB` are a domain model interface and entity framework entity respectively.  There is a direct (and unique) mapping between them, e.g. `SomeService<IPerson, PersonEntity>`.  The entity framework entity part is what I don't want to leak up to my business layer where everything should be in terms of domain model objects, e.g. `IPerson`.

Comment: If it is possible to describe this relationship in a type constraint (e.g. `class SomeService<TA, TB> where TA : IEntity<TB>`), in that case a registration like `container.Register(typeof(ISomeService<>), typeof(SomeService<,>))` would work as is in Simple Injector. Otherwise you will have to specify each mapping explicitly.

Comment: @Steven - No, there is no relationship between the model and entity class that can be defined with a generic type constraint (I could force one, but that would be somewhat contrived).

Answer (score 2):

With Simple Injector, you can make register a partially-closed generic type as follows:

```
container.Register(typeof(ISomeService<>),
    typeof(SomeService<,>).MakeGenericType(
        typeof(SomeService<,>).GetGenericArguments().First(),
        typeof(Bar)),
    Lifestyle.Scoped);
```

There is no other DI library that can handle this, but in this case there is a simple workaround for containers like Autofac; you can simply derive from the type:

```
public class BarSomeService<TA> : SomeService<TA, Bar>
{
    public BarSomeService([dependencies]) : base([dependencies]) { }
}

containerBuilder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(BarSomeService<>))
    .As(typeof(ISomeService<>))
    .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

Comment: Deriving from the type is an interesting workaround, so thanks for the suggestion.  However, I'm not sure that that is preferable to explicitly registering each mapping explicitly.  And if I'm understanding things correctly, the first of your code snippets above would still require explicit registration for each mapping (i.e. the `typeof(Bar)` above).  Thanks again for your thoughts and ideas.  Simple Injector is really impressive by the way!